# Should I use uuid column type for an association in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an article with a UUID and I want to save it's **published** state as well as the user who published it.

In the migration for Article, what column type should I use to reference the User?  The user has a uuid with column type :uuid.

Should I do `t.uuid :published_by` in my Article migration?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using UUID primary key for User, you have to use column type UUID as a reference to User.

You can add reference to User as below:

```
t.references :publisher, type: :uuid, references: :users, foreign_key: { to_table: :users }
```

Also, I'd recommend using the name publisher instead of published_by.

Comment: Thanks, is 'publisher' personal preference or is there something deeper?

Comment: well, not just personal preference, it's like when some article/book is published one would usually say who is the publisher, etc.

Comment: in this case it's not referring to a publishing company, it's referring to the user who clicked the publish button.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely recommend using the primary key for that model; you can determine what this is by running `User.primary_key`.

Additionally, I'd recommend against adding the column by its type (`t.uuid`/`t.integer`/`t.bigint`/etc); instead, use `t.references :user, foreign_key: true`, which will add a column referencing the primary key as well as an index and a foreign-key constraint. See [the docs for `references`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-references) for more information.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the response.  So I already have a 'references' to tie it to the user that created it.  Is it still appropriate to add another 'references' to keep track of who published it?  How would you then name it 'published_by'?

Comment: @Ashbury `t.references :published_by, foreign_key: { to_table: :users }` should work well; and then in the model you'd write `belongs_to :published_by, class_name: 'User'`

Comment: If the primary key in the referenced table is NOT `bigint`, you need to specify the type. Most particularly, if the primary key is `uuid`, then you have to add `type: :uuid` to the `t.references` command. Otherwise it defaults to `bigint` and will fail. During migrations, rails does not have your models loaded and and does not inspect the current state of the database, so it does now know what type the primary key is.